# How to use setState after a css transition ends in React JS?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, css-transforms, react-class-based-component

```
//sample piece of codes

constructor() {
    super()
  this.state.opacity= '0'
  this.state.mover = 'translateY(-40%)'
 }


this.setState({opacity:'1'})
this.setState({mover: 'translateY(-900%)'}, () => {this.setState({opacity:'0'})})
```

when I click on a button, I want a div to appear (using opacity 1) and transition to top and fade out after reaching the top(using opacity 0).

But it didn't work the way I expected. Currently, it fades out instantly. It doesn't wait for the transition to end. I want it to fade out **after** the transition ends.

Is there a way in React to fix it ? I am very new in react. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think the only way to solve this issue is using 'react-transition-group'. I have to do a POC to confirm though. https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an easy workaround for this. I am not sure if this is the right way, but it works.

```
constructor() {
super()
this.state.opacity= '0'
this.state.mover = 'translateY(-40%)'
}


this.setState({opacity:'1'})
this.setState({mover: 'translateY(-900%)'}, () => {
               setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ opacity: '0' })}, 1000);
               })
```

Inside the call back function, I setup a settimeout function. The event inside the settimeout function will be triggered after xxx milliseconds. So basically you will have to calculate the duration of your previous transition and set the time accordingly.

Comment: This is definitely not the right way... in general you shouldn't be hard-coding setTimeouts like that. It's not really a big deal in this context, but I'd also consider using CSS animations.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `transitionend` event listener?

```
yourDivElement.addEventListener('transitionEnd', (event) => { 
   this.setState({ yourProp: "your-new-value" })
}, false );
```

Annoyingly enough, you may need to add different event names for cross browser compatibility:

```
["transitionend", "webkitTransitionEnd", "mozTransitionEnd"].forEach((eventName) => {
    yourDivElement.addEventListener(eventName, (event) => { 
       this.setState({ yourProp: "your-new-value" })
    }, false );
})
```

Make sure you refer to the DOM element using `ref`.

[Browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_transitionend_event)
[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event)